# Size limit of character varying Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, varchar

What is the size limit of various data types in postgresql? I saw somewhere that for `character varying(n)`, `varchar(n)` `n` must be between 1 to 10485760. Is that true?

What are the valid sizes for `character(n)`, `char(n)` and `text`?

Answer (score 66, accepted):

The maximum size of limited character types (e.g. varchar(n)) in Postgres is 10485760. You can check this in that way:

```
create table test(id serial primary key, str varchar(10485761));

ERROR:  length for type varchar cannot exceed 10485760
```

The limit is defined in the following fragment of source code (htup_details.h), however is not explicitly mentioned in the official documentation:

```
/*
 * MaxAttrSize is a somewhat arbitrary upper limit on the declared size of
 * data fields of char(n) and similar types.  It need not have anything
 * directly to do with the *actual* upper limit of varlena values, which
 * is currently 1Gb (see TOAST structures in postgres.h).  I've set it
 * at 10Mb which seems like a reasonable number --- tgl 8/6/00.
 */
#define MaxAttrSize     (10 * 1024 * 1024)
```

The maximum number of characters for variable unlimited length types (text, varchar) is undefined. There is a limit of size in bytes for [all string types](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-character.html):

> In any case, the longest possible character string that can be stored is about 1 GB.